# PySpark: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

Tags: pyspark, netezza

I have spark code which connects to Netezza and reads a table.

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("app").setMaster("yarn-client")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
hc = HiveContext(sc)

nz_df=hc.load(source="jdbc",url=address dbname";username=;password=",dbtable="")
```

I do spark-submit and run the code in the following way..
spark-submit -jars nzjdbc.jar filename.py

And I get the following exception:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o55.load.
: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
```

Am I doing anything wrong over here?? is the jar not suitable or is it not able to recgonize the jar?? please let me know the correct way if this is not and also can anyone provide the link to get the jar for connecting netezza from spark.

I am using the 1.6.0 version of spark.

Comment: Do you have right drivers in place?

Comment: yes I do have drivers in path which I specified before running the code..